Htaccess Url Rewrite using bootstrap scrollspy
im using bootstrap scrollspy and have links like this:
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
https://example.com/#contact

Is it possible with htacces rewrite the url to
https://example.com/contact


Your question is unclear ... Please take a bit of time to revise it, there is an "edit" link below it, use that ... Why would you want to rewrite this? What is it you want to achieve? What for? It is hard for us to offer help if your question lacks precision.

And a general hint: such links with a hash tag ("#") are called "in page anchors". They are interpreted by the browser itself, not by the server side. Meaning that no request is actually sent to the server if a user clicks such a link. It is a "client side only reference" inside the already loaded. Since there is not request sent there is no request to be processed on the server side. So no rewriting can get applied ...

What you can do is alter the reference you send out in the first place, so that it reads /contact. That would result in a request sent to the server, that is something you can actually rewrite, if you need to. But altering that reference itself can not be done by means of rewriting. That would mean altering your application logic. Or applying server side substitutions to the delivered resources, which rarely is a good idea for various reasons. Typically that means you should question your general approach.

If you want these URLs to be used as "entry points" from the outside, then you can of course rewrite /contact to your index.htm(l)/index.php or whatever you have there. Then you'd need an additional script in there, that detects that the URL this was loaded with, was actually /contact - and then make it "go" to the content behind the #contact anchor directly. And by subscribing to the activate.bs.scrollspy event, you could probably update the URL shown in the browser address bar to /contact, when the #contact element gets scrolled into view.
